# Placing httpd config outside /etc/httpd/conf

Tags: shell, unix, httpd.conf

I'm searching for a way to locate my httpd service configuration file outside of the /etc/httpd/config folder; for example in /test. 
Do you know how I can do that and still can start the service with
     systemctl start httpd
?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Option 1:
If your web server is apache, you could use an include directive in your main httpd.conf file to include settings in a file at a custom path:

```
    Include /test/custom.conf
```

Option 2:
Apache has it's conf location set at compile time, however, it is possible to launch apache with a custom configuration file:

```
    /usr/local/apache2/bin/apachectl -f /test/httpd.conf
```

This is assuming your apachectl is located in  /usr/local/apache2/bin. To find out for sure:

```
    # updatedb
    # locate apachectl
```

This means you would need to alter the startup script for your apache server to launch with a command that specifies the -f parameter.

Comment: Thanks :) Apachectl however won't  work, it says -f is not longer supported. What works for me is httpd -f /path/httpd.conf